# Unable to run my first Selenium and Python test

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

It seems like I am missing some configuration in order to run tests properly.
Steps I followed:
-In a new folder I create a "main.py" file.
-Created a new virtual environment through terminal using "python3 -m venv .venv" command
-Clicked "Yes" on the "We noticed a new environment has been created. Do you want to use it" message on my IDE
-Killed the terminal and executed the following code by running "python3 main.py" command

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
 % python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/mechanized/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Comment: Why are you passing `'./chromedriver'` as an argument to `Chrome()`?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I don't think you need to add anything in between the parenthesis because I believe in Python, that means you're passing a variable to the library which it may not understand or require.